# Laravel mostrar columna de otra tabla desde edit

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy haciendo el edit de la tabla franquicias la cual tiene una llave a la tabla empresa en el metodo edit tengo esto:

```
    public function edit($fra_id)

{
    $empresas = empresa::all();
   $franquicia = franquicia::findOrFail($fra_id);

   return view('franquicias.edit',compact('franquicia'), compact('empresas'));

}
```

lo cual me devuelve los datos de todas las empresas para llenar un Select
y los datos de la franquicia a modificar pero me devuelve el id de la empresa y quiero mostrar el nombre

Comment: en los modelos solo tengo definido esto class franquicia extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey ='fra_id';
}

Comment: la tabla franquicia tiene la llave emp_id que conecta a empresa con emp_id

Comment: relacion de uno a uno , y recuperar los datos de la franquicia junto con el nombre de la empresa

Answer (score 0):

Primero necesitas declarar las relaciones de Eloquent a nivel de los modelos, recordando que para este caso utilizarás:

- Una empresa *hasOne* a franquicia
- Una franquicia *belongsTo* a una empresa

Modelo Empresa

```
class Empresa extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = "aqui la llave primaria de este modelo";

    public function franquicia()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Franquicia::class, 'llave_foranea');
    }
}
```

Modelo Franquicia

```
class Franquicia extends Model 
{
    protected $primaryKey = "aqui la llave primaria de este modelo";

    public function empresa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class, 'llave_foranea');
    }
}
```

Ahora para recuperar los datos de una franquicia en específico y el nombre de la empresa con la cual esta asociada puedes construir tu consulta así

```
$consulta = Franquicia::with('empresa')->findOrFail($fra_id);
```

Donde estamos cargando al modelo Franquicia con la relación empresa declarada en el mismo modelo y filtramos de todas las franquicias, solo aquella que se corresponda por el `id_fra` que llega en dicha variable.

- [Aquí la documentación para consultar mas al respecto](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: deje asi:
        return $this->hasOne(Franquicia::class, 'emp_id');

        return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class, 'emp_id');
 y en edit.blade.php hago esta llamada: value="{{$franquicia->emp_nom}}"> pero solo me devuelve vacio